# Getting error 500 when adding RewriteCond with .to domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect traffic coming from a specific domain inside my .htaccess file. It works fine unless I do this for a domain with a .to extension. Any idea what is going on here?

Produces error 500:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}            ^(www\.)?domain\.to [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$                    /foo/bar [L]
```

Works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}            ^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$                    /foo/bar [L]
```

Comment: What Apache's error log says about this error?

Comment: Looks like it's getting stuck in a recursive loop. "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Comment: Also tried: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?domain\.to
RewriteCond $1      !^(/foo/bar) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$      /foo/bar [L]

Comment: What is the real rule? Are both of these domains pointing to the same folder (the same .htaccess .. and these rules are next to each other)? I mean -- any of these rules on it's own can easily create a rewrite loop. Definitely need more details. -- would be good to have full .htaccess (rewrite rules) contents.

Comment: Both domains are on the same doc root, for the .to domain want to deep link into application. I tried adding an exception which would not redirect it if it was already in the correct location (comment #3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not know for sure which rule does produce rewrite loop, I can only suggest this approach at this moment:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.to [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/bar
RewriteRule ^.*$ /foo/bar [L]
```

Your attempt is not technically correct for 2 reasons:

- in .htaccess URL will be without leading slash (I'm referring to `$1`);
- you are using `$1` .. but you have no matching group setup (in other words `$1` will always be empty).

---

If still nothing -- please provide real htaccess ... or try enabling **rewrite debugging** (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) -- but for this you have to have full control over Apache server, as this directive cannot be placed in .htaccess (only server config / virtual host context) + you will need to restart Apache to re-read configuration file.

---

Try adding this rule somewhere on the top -- where it will be appropriate:

```
# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
```

Comment: This is my real htaccess. # Direct default wayfinding directions
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?bleau\.to [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !^/SERVICE/directions
RewriteRule ^.*$      /SERVICE/directions [L]

Comment: Tried turning on debugging level 9, and it outputs a huge anount of data. This is in a production environment, so it is quite hard to see which debugging is me vs other traffic. I would need to change DNS to staging for better testing.

Comment: Do you have other rewrite rules in .htaccess? Because mod_rewrite works in iterations (when rewrite occurs it goes to next iteration and start matching all rules again from top) .. it is possible that you have this because some other rule changes URL from `/SERVICE/directions` to something else ... and on text iteration it get's rewritten again .. and again. This rule on it's own will not produce rewrite loop. Try adding "do not rewrite existing files/folders" rule -- see my updated answer (in 1 min or 2).

Comment: It's not a physical file. This is in a CMS, so everything goes through one place (there is a global rewrite at the bottom). I was hoping it would work like this: Request comes in through .to, rewrite request uri to deep link into specific area in cms (still under .to), request continues through mod_rewrite get's caught by global and is sent into index.php